# Server GRPC core Implementation of GRPC.core in .NET framework 4.8

Tags: grpc-dotnet, protobuf-net.grpc

Samples for grpc.core server implementation in .NET framework 4.7

We are planning to migrate from .NET framework to .NET core (.NET6). As part of this migration, we want to first move to grpc.core from WCF. When we searched for sample service implementation using grpc.core in .NET frameowrk 4.7, we ended up getting nothing. All the results were pointed to the implementation using grpcdotent in dotnet6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a grpc.core server and client [hello world example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/v1.46.x/examples/csharp/Helloworld)

This example's server project targets .NET Core 3.1 but you can essentially use the same code/approach for .NET 4.7

Comment: Thanks Cale .. Looked into it and it helped out. I also created a example for DotNetFramework specific. let me check whether i can push the changes.